# I can not implement threejs model to my own website

Tags: three.js

https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cars I can not run the following link on my own computer. Despite downloading the necessary files and adjusting the pathways, the car model does not appear. What is the solution? The implementation's code is https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_materials_cars.html

Comment: I really need this solution thanks for helps.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! In order to help you, we need to see what you did. There are just so many ways things can go wrong that its hard to answer your question. Did you open the developer-tools? Is there something written in the console, like an error-message maybe?

Comment: I do not get any errors in the console. But I do not see the car models that appear on the link I have left everything else; Buttons, backgrounds etc. But I can not show car models anyhow.

Comment: is it possible to provide a link or post the code you are running and some details about how you are opening it?

Comment: I explain that I downloaded the files from https://threejs.org this link download. Here are examples made with threejs. One of these examples, "webgl_materials_cars.html", also came with the files in this example. When I run the example named "webgl_materials_cars.html" on my computer, it does not look like "threejs" in its own site. . So everything looks, but not just the car model. I can not find the problem.

Comment: So, are you opening the example via an URL starting with `file://`? That won't work. You will need to have some http-server to serve the files.